# How to get results from multiple local sql database tables?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm creating an app in android studio and i have some questions stored in a database which is created when the user opens the app for the first time and i created another database so the user can add his questions and i need to take a random question from out of these 2 databases.Each database have 3 same columns 1.question 2.heat 3.gender
Here's what i already tried but don't work.

```
    public Cursor getQuestion(int HeatLevel, int Gender) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT question, heat, gender FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " WHERE heat = " + HeatLevel + " AND  gender = " + Gender +
                    " UNION ALL" +
                    " SELECT question, heat, gender FROM " + SECOND_TABLE_NAME +
                    " WHERE heat = " + HeatLevel + " AND gender = " + Gender +
                    " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return data;
        }
```

So the app chooses a question from the database based on the difficulty and the players gender.
The above code produces an error saying "No such table" and the name of the second database like it can't find it.

i get the question in another activity using this

```
    public void getQuestion(int HeatLevel, int Gender) {
            Cursor question = QuestionDB.getQuestion(HeatLevel, Gender);
            if (question.moveToNext()) {
                QuestionTextView.setText(question.getString(0));
            }
        }
```

I'm new to sql so maybe the query is wrong.

Comment: why you are not using Room? it's easy to use and very help full

Comment: I could use that but i already have thoose 2 databases in 4 activities for adding,editing and deleting them, will it be worth to restart this part?Is it really that easy to use?

Comment: Did you really create *2 databases* or do you mean **2 tables**? If you created 2 database then you found the problem.

Comment: I think i have 2 tables.I have the 2 files with the tables names 1 and 2 in my app folder in my phone called databases.If i created 2 different databases wouldn't they(The tables) be on  a separately folder?Do i need to create those 2 tables in the onCreate of 1 class?

Comment: Yeah that's it i just changed the onCreate so it creates the tables in 1 database and i add edit and delete data from this 1 class.thank you @forpas making me think the right way.